# Problem with Gradle and UNC path under Jenkins

Tags: cmd, gradle, unc, jenkins

Got this error after moving %JENKINS_HOME% to a UNC from a local directory.  Any idea how to fix this?  We use Windows server 2008 and it seems like there is no way to do hard link to a UNC under Server 2008.  Has anyone ran into this problem?

All the build tools are stored under \\UNCPath\BuildTools

%JENKINS_HOME% = \\UNCPath\JenkinsHome

> [workspace] $ cmd.exe /C \\UNCPath\BuildTools\gradle\1.0\bin\gradle.bat clean jar cobertura test groovyDoc && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
>   '\\UNCPath\JenkinsHome\jobs\Project\workspace'
>   CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>   UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
>       at java.io.File.(File.java:368)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassPathProvider$ClassPathScanner.find(AbstractClassPathProvider.java:146)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassPathProvider.findClassPath(AbstractClassPathProvider.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPathFiles(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPathUrls(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:28)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
>   Recording test results
>   Publishing Javadoc
>   Skipping Cobertura coverage report as build was not UNSTABLE or better ...
>   Finished: FAILURE
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd.exe doesn't support UNC paths. You have to use PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle may not be able to handle UNC paths, not sure on that one. What you could do, since you are using Win2008 is use a sym link

`mklink /D c:\jenkins_home \\UNCPath\BuildTools`

Then set %JENKINS_HOME% = c:\jenkins_home

Comment: +1 - I'm surprised that it can't support a mapped drive still.  mklink is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Map a drive won't work. %JENKINS_HOME% doesn't like a mapped drive letter. However, I just found this link to do registry change and the check for UNC is eliminated.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156276

Now I have an URI problem:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
>       at java.io.File.(File.java:368)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassPathProvider$ClassPathScanner.find(AbstractClassPathProvider.java:146)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassPathProvider.findClassPath(AbstractClassPathProvider.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPathFiles(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPathUrls(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:28)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you map a drive letter?

> net use X: \UNCPath\BuildTools
>
> x:\script.bat
>
> net use X: /d

Comment: Map a drive won't work.  %JENKINS_HOME% doesn't like a mapped drive letter.  However, I just found this registry change and the check for UNC is eliminated.  Now I have this problem:

Comment: What error do you get if you assign %JENKINS_HOME% to a mapped drive letter ?